# Generate Custom array when Select using relation table on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a problem when i want to select data from database.

this is my query

```
SELECT J.id as id_job, J.title as job_title, J.companies_id, C.name as company_name,J.created_at, L.name as Location,CL.postal_code, CL.address
                                FROM jobs J
                                INNER JOIN bla1 C ON ( C.id = J.company_id )
                                INNER JOIN bla2 CL ON ( CL.id = J.company_location_id )
                                INNER JOIN bla3 L ON ( L.id = CL.location_id )
                                WHERE J.status =1
                                AND C.status =2
                                And CL.status = 1
                                AND L.status = 1
                                ORDER BY J.created_at DESC
                                LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and this is the result of that query using `var_dump()`

```
["_result":protected]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id_job"]=>
      string(2) "27"
      ["job_title"]=>
      string(10) "YUYUYUYUYU"
      ["company_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["company_name"]=>
      string(16) "voyage indonesia"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2012-10-03 09:35:37"
      ["Location"]=>
      string(4) "Bali"
      ["postal_code"]=>
      string(6) "989767"
      ["address"]=>
      string(11) "dimana mana"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id_job"]=>
      string(2) "23"
      ["job_title"]=>
      string(11) "OYEEEEAAHHH"
      ["company_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["company_name"]=>
      string(16) "voyage indonesia"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2012-09-28 09:06:54"
      ["Location"]=>
      string(7) "Bandung"
      ["postal_code"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id_job"]=>
      string(2) "20"
      ["job_title"]=>
      string(14) "TKPDKJKLADKSJA"
      ["company_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["company_name"]=>
      string(16) "voyage indonesia"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2012-09-20 09:24:50"
      ["Location"]=>
      string(7) "Bandung"
      ["postal_code"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      NULL
    }
}
["_total_rows":protected]=>
  int(3)
  ["_current_row":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["_as_object":protected]=>
  bool(false)
```

my goal : example in array index at 8 like this or something else better than this code

```
array(8) {
          ["id_job"]=>
          string(2) "27"
          ["job_title"]=>
          string(10) "YUYUYUYUYU"
          ["company_id"]=>
          string(1) "3"
          Array ( [companies] => array(1) {
          ["company_name"]=>
          string(16) "voyage indonesia"
          })
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(19) "2012-10-03 09:35:37"
          ["Location"]=>
          string(4) "Bali"
          ["postal_code"]=>
          string(6) "989767"
          ["address"]=>
          string(11) "dimana mana"
        }
```

company_id is relation table database table bla1,
i want to giving array in relation table, so I can easily to parse data,
like `array('bla1' = > array('company_id',1));`
any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you explain your goal a bit better? I don't get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
 array[$row_id] = $row;
```

Comment: yeah but where i can place that code, on my query or i must loop and generate array manually?

Comment: its not in your query, its in the results in php.  Probably something like $result = mysql_query($sql)  while($result) { $variable[] = $row  }  inside the [] set Whatever the second variable in this case Row to..  $variable[$row['id_job']]

Comment: thanks for answer, if in the result of php how i can detect that's field is from relation table or not,i'm worried if so many relation it's will be problem i think...

Comment: You have to get the query first and all results. After that you can ask for array[$row_id] = $row as @Iscariot said.

Comment: thanks i have imagine from your answer, i will try if i can fix this i will post my answer...:)

Comment: post the code you run AFTER you run the SQL call.  You're not quite getting it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you can get nested arrays from an SQL query.
A database query delivers rows and columns without further substructure.

You can of course do this programmatically, by just taking your tables with jobs and locations as arrays and then generate the desired nested list from  this. However, then you're losing the power of the join, and need to embed it into your code.